# Azure Model to TableServiceEntity in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have an MVC 4 site up and running. For now I have been using localDB and I want to change this so that everything is read from and written to Azure Table Storage.

This is not that hard to do, but it rises a design question for me: I don't want to implement TableServiceEntity directly on my model for 2 reasons:

- I have business wise properties like ID and I don't want to have the rowkey / partition key fields to replace them (or have them duplicate the values in there)
- And most importantly: one does not want the models to know where they are written to (that should be hidden from the models)

So the question is: what is the best approach here? 
(use DTO / automapper / ... ?)

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple notes about your scenario and Azure tables

1. Take a look at the 3.0 [release](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) of the client which has dramatic performance improvements for tables, including [JSON](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/12/05/windows-azure-tables-introducing-json.aspx) light /nometadata
2. I highly recommend utilizing the Table service layer which provides the TableEntity, ITableEntity, and DynamicTableEntity types.

You have a few options here, the first is to use the TableEntity object and customize the serialization by overriding ITableEntity.Read/Write entity. This will allow you to change property names / values etc during serialization / deserialization.

You can also use a DTO type as you mentioned, but then you must maintain the object separately etc. 
In this [teched](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/WAD-B406#fbid=ahHKx_XgyAx) talk at ~40:30  I demonstrated how to use a generic EntityAdapter class to directly persist 3rd party objects that did not Derive from TableEntity or implement the ITableEntity interface. (You can find the source of the examples [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-Storage-675fe55b).) This approach would allow you to persist any object type to Azure Tables without exposing any dependency on storage itself.

Comment: I took a look at the code and at first it was daunting :) (I am a Dynamics Ax developer... ;-) )

Just watched you TechEd session and the explanation got me up to speed. Nice EntityAdapter thing there and that's just what I need!!

Comment: I have implemented  the table storage for one of my Repositories and I got it working.

There is one more thing though. I notice a note in your sample code mentioning something about putting in a where clause. Now I get an error that I cannot use the linq where<> clause because of the type being a DynamicEntity instead of my model type.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented  the table storage for one of my Repositories and I got it working.
There is one more thing though.

I notice a note in your sample code mentioning something about putting in a where clause. 
This is a method that I use in the repository that gets a collection of Benificiary records:

```
IQueryable<Benificiary> retrievedBenificiaries = (from entry in table.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>() select entry).Resolve(EntityAdapter.AdapterResolver<Benificiary>);
```

So this returns an `IQueryable<Benificiary>` and in my controller that receives it, I want to do the following:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Benificiary benificiary = benificiaryRepository.GetAll().Where(b => b.BenificiaryID == id).First();
        if (benificiary == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(benificiary);
    }
```

But the Where clause pops up an error :

**{"Expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[HomeConstructionManager.Models.Benificiary]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[HomeConstructionManager.Models.Benificiary] Where[Benificiary](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[HomeConstructionManager.Models.Benificiary], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[HomeConstructionManager.Models.Benificiary,System.Boolean]])'"}**

The only thing that I did to make it work was first doing the ToList and apply the where clause then.

```
Benificiary benificiary = benificiaryRepository.GetAll().ToList<Benificiary>().Where(b => b.BenificiaryID == id).First();
```

Should I do this like this or is there a better way to do this?

Also, I noticed that when I use the EntityAdapter, it nicely fills the rowkey and partition key but the properties still exists so it is stored double in the storage table.